# How can I pause a loop in processing js?

Tags: javascript, processing

Here's a modified loop from the widthheight.html example of the processing.js tutorial

```
flag=1;
for(int i=0; i<height; i+=20) 
{    if (flag)
     {   fill(0);    rect(0, i, width, 10);
         fill(255);  rect(i, 0, 10, height);
         if (mousePressed()){flag=0; }
         if (mouseReleased()){flag=1; }
    }
}
```

I added the flag and the mousePress stuff to try to step through, but the loop steps once and then won't run at all with that in it. And it pays no attention to the mouse.

The flag itself seems to control the loop, but I see no way to set it interactively.

I've also tried replacing the flag with noLoop and loop, and that doesn't restart it either.

I see no command in the list of commands that would pause or even delay inside a loop.

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet?

Comment: Btw you probably want to tag this with [tag:processing.js] instead of [tag:javascript] because you aren't using JavaScript syntax here.

Comment: Here's the entire file as posted on the tutorial site:
<html><head>
  <script src="../../processing.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/></head>
<body><h1><a href="http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/">Processing.js</a></h1>
<h2>WidthHeight</h2>
<p><a href="http://processing.org/learning/basics/widthheight.html"><b>Original Processing.org Example:</b> WidthHeight</a><br>
<script type="application/processing">
size(200, 200);
background(127);
noStroke();
for(int i=0; i<height; i+=20) { fill(0); rect(0, i, width, 10); fill(255); rect(i, 0, 10, height);}

Answer (score 0):

The `noLoop()` function will stop the `draw()` loop being called 60 times per second.

I think your problem is probably caused by these lines:

```
if (mousePressed())
if (mouseReleased())
```

That's not how these functions work. These are both functions that you have to define yourself, that Processing will then call for you when the mouse is pressed or released. Calling them like this doesn't make any sense. You might be looking for the `mousePressed` variable.

I recommend you read [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) on input in Processing.

**Edit:** Here are a couple basic examples:

```
void draw(){
   if(mousePressesd){
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
   }
}
```

This example only draws something if the mouse is pressed. Notice I'm using the `mousePressed` **variable** instead of trying to call a function.

Or you could use the `noLoop()` and `loop()` function, like this:

```
void draw(){
   ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

void mousePressed(){
   noLoop();
}

void keyPressed(){
   loop();
}
```

This example defines a `mousePressed()` function that is automatically called when the mouse is pressed, and when that happens it pauses the `draw()` loop. You can unpause it by pressing a key.

Taking a step back, I'll recommend that in the future you take the time to understand what an answer is telling you before you dismiss it. All of the above is explained in my original answer, as well as in the tutorial I linked.

If you still can't get it working then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has addressed the errors I've pointed out in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I Know that it stops processing. So, How Do I pause a loop, and restart it? Is it impossible to do that in processingjs?

Comment: @user1067305 Before downvoting, please understand what I'm trying to tell you. Did you read the tutorial I linked? Did you read the fact that you shouldn't call the `mousePressed()` or `mouseReleased()` functions? Did you read that there is a `mousePressed` variable you could be using? Did you read my answer at all? No it's not impossible. But if you're just going to downvote without understanding what I'm saying, then I'll happily spend my time on other questions. Good luck.

Comment: The question was about PAUSING a loop, not about mousePress! I just tried that as a possible way to do it. Even without content, it killed looping. If you know a way to pause and restart the default looping, please feel free to express it.

Comment: @user1067305 Please see my edited answer. But you should really get into the habit of trying to understand what an answer is telling you, and then trying to address the issues pointed out, before dismissing it. We can't just do your work for you. We can just point you in the right direction and have you do the reading and experimenting. That's how programming works.